# найти уникальные значения клиентов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо найти уникальные значения клиентов с 01.06.2022 по 30.09.2022, при учете того, что уникальным считается тот клиент, у которого не было оформленных заявок за последние 12 месяцев. То есть для июня 2022 уникальными будут те, у которых не было заявок с 30 мая 2021 года.

```
select idclient, date
from table_a
where date between to_date ('01.06.2022','dd.mm.yyy') and to_Date ('30.09.2022','dd.mm.yyyy')
and idclient not in 
(select idclient
from table_a
Where date between to_date ('01.06.2021','dd.mm.yyy') and to_Date ('30.05.2022','dd.mm.yyyy'))
```

Остановился на этом, дальше никак не могу придумать как вывести уникальные данные.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Уточните СУБД, судя по to_date у вас скоррее всего Postgres или Oracle. А вообще вам поможет.

Comment: А, тут ещё поле date - тогда Postgres, Oracle ругнулся бы. Метку добавил.